# DataFrame very slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with date indexes made of more than 17000 rows.
For each row, I have a power consumption, the temperature and the date as indexe of the dataframe. There are also 4 others columns where there dates with various formats.

For each row if the date >= 08/01/2019, I am doing:

Consumption(date) = Consumption(date) - Consumption(date-1week)

Temperature(date) = Temperature(date) - Temperature(date-1week)

But it is very very slow (like 4 minutes...)

The result is good, but I cannot manage to speed up the process.

I am wondering is the approrach is correct as I am starting using python ?
Maybe the fact that there are 4 columns I am not using here for this calculation slow down the process?

Here is a part of the code that takes a huge amount of time with df the dataframe I described above.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if index >= datetime(year,1,8,0,0):
       date_start_j_wb = index - timedelta(days=7)

       conso_j = df[df.index == index]["conso"].values
       conso_j_wb = df[df.index == date_start_j_wb]["conso"].values
       temp_j = df[df.index == index]["temp"].values
       temp_j_wb = df[df.index == date_start_j_wb]["temp"].values
       s_dconso = conso_j[0] - conso_j_wb[0]
       s_dtemp =  temp_j[0] - temp_j_wb[0]
```

Here is what look likes the dataframe as maybe it is because of the number of date column that the code is so slow:

```
df["start_date"] = start_date
df["start_hour"]= start_hour
df["end_hour"] = end_hour
df["start_date_hour"] = start_date_hour
df["start_date_hour_str"] = start_date_hour_str
df["end_date_hour_str"] = end_date_hour_str
df["end_date_hour"] = end_date_hour
df["end_hour"] = end_hour
df["conso"] = conso
df["temp"] = temp
```

Could you please give me advice to speed up this code.
With this amount of data, I would though that it would not take more than 1 min...

Thank you in advance,

Comment: `for index, row in df.iterrows()` is always going to be slow, especially when you do: `df[df.index == index]["conso"].values` **inside** that loop, because that scans the *entire dataframe* each loop, doing that *multiple times in your loop body is highly inefficient*. Do you have duplicate indices, why are you doing that anyway? In any case, `iterrows` should always be a last resort (and even then you should use `.itertuples`). Always prefer built-in, vectorized pandas functions

Comment: There is likely a very straightforward and efficient way to accomplish what you are doing. You should provide an example data-frame *in the question* and describe exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just wish to support @juanpa.arrivillaga  comments. The power of pandas is in vector calculations. Using for loops and tools like iterrows should be a last resort. I think we can help you find a very fast solution, but we need to see your dataframe you are working with and perhaps a sample of what you would like the output to be. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hum ok I see, doing like that I am not taking advantage of vector calculation at all...but I can't see other way.

My data frame look like that (one year with 30 min step):

```
                 start_date start_hour  ...  conso      temp
  start_date_hour                             ...                 
  2019-01-01 00:00:00  2019-01-01      00:00  ...  0.057  5.684032
  2019-01-01 00:30:00  2019-01-01      00:30  ...  0.057  5.663681
  2019-01-01 01:00:00  2019-01-01      01:00  ...  0.057  5.655579
  2019-01-01 01:30:00  2019-01-01      01:30  ...  0.056  5.655822
  2019-01-01 02:00:00  2019-01-01      02:00  ...  0.057  5.664895
  2019-01-01 02:30:00  2019-01-01      02:30  ...  0.057  5.654780
  .....
```

As I told before, for each row, I check if the index is superior or equal to 2019-01-08, if so I look at the "conso" and "temp" one week ago and then I do the different between the "conso" at the date "D" minus the "conso" a the date (D-1week)
Here the output is a consumption variation and temperature variation for each row from 08/01/2019.

Then I multiply Delta_Consumption with Delta_temperature  and  Delta_temperature with Delta_temperature.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():


    if index >= datetime(year,1,8,0,0):
       date_start_j_wb = index - timedelta(days=7)

       conso_j = df[df.index == index]["conso"].values
       conso_j_wb = df[df.index == date_start_j_wb]["conso"].values
       temp_j = df[df.index == index]["temp"].values
       temp_j_wb = df[df.index == date_start_j_wb]["temp"].values

       s_dconso = conso_j[0] - conso_j_wb[0]
       s_dtemp =  temp_j[0] - temp_j_wb[0]

       prodtemp = s_dtemp*s_dtemp
       prodtemp_conso = s_dtemp*s_dconso
```

Then I store the result "prodtemp" and "prodtemp_conso" in two list. The goal is actualy to do a linear regression basically.

As I then divide prodtemp_conso by prodtemp and then sum each same half hour period.

But the part of the code I mentionned above, is the part that slow everything..

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to find an other solution, that works faster, but not elegant at all.

I created 5 list: one before the first change of hour, one for the day of change of hour, one after the first day of hour change and before the second, an other for the second day hour change and a last one after...

Then I added two values for the list for the first hour change and deleted two values for the list of the second hour change.As a consequence I have 48 elements in boths.

I concatenated the 5 lists, and created two list: one I shift of 48*7 from the beginning and the other from the end. Then the operation is easy.

It is wrong from the step of hour changes, but those two step are not important for me.

But it is not really clean.... Would you have some advice ?